# React native- How to create a json object and json array

Tags: json, react-native

How to create a json object with json array inside in it in react native. I have a situation to post json object with array to some api call

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? in what kind of situation? or if you are looking to convert existing things to JSON you can use `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var jsonArray = [];
var jsonObject = { name : 'abc',age : 27, gender : 'Male'};
jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
console.log('jsonArray=',jsonArray);

var jsonArray2 = { jsonArray : jsonArray};
console.log('jsonArray2=',jsonArray2);
```

Final Output

```
"jsonArray=", [{
  age: 27,
  gender: "Male",
  name: "abc"
}]

"jsonArray2=", {
  jsonArray: [{
  age: 27,
  gender: "Male",
  name: "abc"
}]
}
```